# How to extract a url in GoogleSheets using REGEXTRACT

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract a url from the following using regex in googlesheets. I can't get the regex to stop at the double quotes without a parse error.

[Visit W3Schools.com!](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/apple-airpods-pro-white/5706659.p?skuId=5706659)

=REGEXTRACT(F4,"https.*""""")

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(F4,"(https?.+)/")
```